# Mispronounced 'Innaka hamidun majid' as 'Innaka hamidum majid'

Tags: salat, arabic, mistake, helping

Assalamualaikum, I've been praying all of Ramadan and trying to for the past year (onlu started a year ago) and I only just realised I've been pronouncing 'hamidun' as 'hamidum'. Is there any sin on me for missed prayers and are they all invalid even if I had no clue? I've also only come to the realisation that I've been pronouncing 'an amta' as 'an anta'. When writing notes on how to pray a year ago (because Idk Arabic) I accidentally and stupidly wrote the 'amta' in a way that looks like 'anta' and I've been pronouncing it this way for a long timw I think so an answer would be helpful in calming my panicked state. Thank you.

Comment: Mispronouciation where exactly? In a qur'an recitation (which verse) ? In a du'a?... This post could use some elaboration and additional information.

Comment: I think "Innaka hamidum majid" is in fact the correct pronunciation. Hear the last part of this verse: https://quran.com/11/73

Comment: Be aware that the pronunciation may be different due to tajweed rules.